# Checkbox states are graphically incorrect in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin, android-checkbox

I'm working on `RecyclerView` with selectable items using `CheckBoxes`. I want to achieve checkable items with following rules:

- Only **ONE** item can be checked at the same time
- If item is checked, this item cannot be unchecked (there **cant be zero** items checked)

Each item has one selected checkbox at start programmatically (default is first). Reason for that is simple. Each item in ArrayList is custom object which has checkbox state represented as boolean inside and you will be able to save states and open them again later.

So I used s`etOnCheckedChangeListener()` for my `CheckBox` and each time I will iterate through the `Arraylist` of items and set `isChecked` to `true` only if it's position is equal to position in `tag`.

This is working well. I've checked each state through debugger and states are correct, but graphical representation is incorrect and I don't know why.

This is graphical representation:

[image]

`onBindViewHolder()` code:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int){

        try {
            if (holder is ViewHolder){

                val res = holder.itemView.context.resources
                val ctx = holder.itemView.context
                foodVariants[position].let{

                    //food variant vals
                    val variantID: Int = it.foodVariant.getInt(ctx.getString(R.string.food_variant_id))
                    val variantName: String? = it.foodVariant.getString(ctx.getString(R.string.food_variant_name))
                    val variantPrice: Int = it.foodVariant.getInt(ctx.getString(R.string.food_variant_price))

                    //set food variant name
                    holder.foodVariantName.text = variantName

                    //set food variant price
                    val variantPriceConverted: String = convertCentsToFloat(variantPrice)
                    holder.foodVariantPrice.text = variantPriceConverted + " €"

                    //set item tag
                    holder.foodVariantCheckBox.tag = position

                    //set food variant state
                    holder.foodVariantCheckBox.isChecked = it.isChecked

                    //uncheck all variants if this is checked - one variant has to be checked everytime
                    holder.foodVariantCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
                        val newPosition = buttonView.tag as Int
                        createLog("VARIANT_STATE: ", "isChecked: " + variantName.toString())
                        for (variantPos in 0 until foodVariants.size){
                            foodVariants[variantPos].isChecked = variantPos == newPosition

                        }
                        mActivity.refreshOtherRecyclerViews(it)
                        notifyDataSetChanged()
                    }
                }


            }
        } catch (e: Exception){
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

    }
```

Comment: Is the widget a CheckBox or a RadioButton?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to move the logic outside of the recycler view. (In the presenter in clean architecture)

You have a list of object `CheckboxModel(val id: Int, val label: String, var isChecked: Boolean)`. When clicking a checkbox, you update your list of CheckboxModel and pass it back to the adapter :

```
fun onUpdate(selectedCase: CheckboxModel) {
     data.forEach { it.isChecked = it.id == selectedCase.id }
     updateAdapter(data)
}
```

You also have to prevent (in the view holder) the unchecking of a checked item when clicking it.

Comment: This is doing same issue as shown above. If I click items from top to bottom, only one item is checked, but if i click previous item, both will be checked.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the my way to implement it

- Make checkbox focusable and focusbleInTouchMode as false
- Take a global variable in adapter ex checkedId .
- In adapter `onBindViewHolder` write a logic

  `if(variantID==checkedId){`

  ```
    holder.foodVariantCheckBox.isChecked=true
  ```

  `}else{`

  `holder.foodVariantCheckBox.isChecked=false`

  `}`
- Set OnclickListener for `holder.foodVariantCheckBox` . In onClick method make checkedId  to variantID and `notifyDataSetChanged()`

  The final checked item id will be in adapter checkedId variable.

Answer (score 0):

So I've combined @Redman 's and @Kélian 's answers to make it work.

This is the final code:

```
private var previouslySelectedVariant: Int = -1

  override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int){

        try {
            if (holder is ViewHolder){

                val res = holder.itemView.context.resources
                val ctx = holder.itemView.context
                foodVariants[position].let{

                    //food variant vals
                    val variantID: Int = it.foodVariant.getInt(ctx.getString(R.string.food_variant_id))
                    val variantName: String? = it.foodVariant.getString(ctx.getString(R.string.food_variant_name))
                    val variantPrice: Int = it.foodVariant.getInt(ctx.getString(R.string.food_variant_price))

                    //set food variant name
                    holder.foodVariantName.text = variantName

                    //set food variant price
                    val variantPriceConverted: String = convertCentsToFloat(variantPrice)
                    holder.foodVariantPrice.text = variantPriceConverted + " €"

                    //set food variant state
                    holder.foodVariantCheckBox.isChecked = it.isChecked

                    //uncheck all variants if this is checked - one variant has to be checked everytime
                    holder.foodVariantCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->

                        if (isChecked) {
                            mActivity.updateVariantData(variantID)
                            mActivity.refreshIngredients(it)
                            previouslySelectedVariant = variantID
                        } else {
                            if(previouslySelectedVariant == variantID){
                                holder.foodVariantCheckBox.isChecked = true
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (e: Exception){
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

    }


//ParentActivity
fun updateVariantData(variantID: Int){
        foodVariantsArray.forEach { it.isChecked = it.foodVariant.getInt(getString(R.string.food_variant_id)) == variantID }
        foodVariantsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
```